# Will Caulk on Steel Door Frame stop Sweating?

Tags: doors

We have a steel door frame that is sweating from the humidity inside. I'm wondering if I can coat the steel with a good caulk, and then put a corner bead (trim) over the caulk? Will the caulk sweat and damage that corner bead?

Comment: What are the actual conditions we're dealing with here? Tropical? Winter? Please revise to add information, including a photo of the frame, if you can.

Comment: I have partially answered my question by performing a small test area. The answer is YES, in that the caulk is "sweating" with the covered steel under it. Since I cannot completely cover the steel frame, my idea is moot. It will always sweat because it's cold metal in a warm house.

Comment: Please take the [tour] for a reminder of how this site works. Upvote answers that are helpful. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small amount of insulation capacity in the caulk and an additional layer of wood trim would contribute as well, so your solution *might* work, but I can only imagine that it won't look really pretty.

The *better* option would be to properly deal with the interior humidity levels, as they can't be doing anything good for any of the other building materials in the room, either. You may *see* the sweat on the steel door frame, but the humidity is going to be lifting paint or curling wall paper, it's eating away at the plaster/drywall on the walls and working its way into whatever (wood/steel) framing is behind them. It's possibly condensing on the sill plates, rotting them, etc.

Comment: You don't say what "properly insulating" would mean here, and cold steel is going to collect moisture regardless of indoor humidity levels. You should see my latch plates this morning, when it's -22F outside.

Comment: Some sort of thermal break, @isherwood. And yes, nothing is going to fully insulate and protect at all times at all temps. I was somewhat vague in that because A) I'm not sure how one would go about providing a thermal break on an existing steel door frame (replace it with one that is? Does such a think exist?), and B) that seems to be a good basis for a whole new question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're going to wrap a door frame without interfering with its operation.

Comment: There, @isherwood, that solved the problem. ;) Honestly, I threw that out as an idea, but with no real idea of how to implement it. I agree with your concerns but thought someone else might have ideas.

Answer (score 0):

**Door hanging.**

[image: door hanging]

[source](https://tradestarexports.com/product/traditional-handmade-door-hanging-patchwork-toran/)

These are called [torans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toran_(art)), it turns out.  I propose you get or make one that covers the frame on top and also runs down along the sides.  This will serve triple duty.  For one, it will insulate the cold frame, which will deplete the air under the fabric of moisture and so limit moisture available to consent.  For two, the fabric (and it should be fabric) will wick away moisture from the frame where it is in contact.

For three, visitors will be impressed at your style sensibilities!  If you are lacking in such I sympathize.  Perhaps you know a style-sensible person who will be flattered to be asked for advice on toran choices.